# Why is $event binding not working on RowGroup tables using PrimeNG?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using RowGroup to store 3 different tables and that works great, but my issue is that the **onRowSelect** function doesn't work at all and because of that when I click on any row of the RowGroup tables, nothing happens.

I also have an external table called **"MY TABLE"** that if you click on any of the row you will get a pop-up with the row info in it. That's the exact functionality I want for my RowGroup tables but I can't get it to work.

Here's my working code: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cjHzNQk8z50EQtwi9Zzz?p=preview)

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" sortField="room" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="room" expandableRowGroups="true"
    [sortableRowGroup]="false" [expandedRowsGroups]="expandedGroups">
  <ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData.room}} - INFO</ng-template>
<p-column field="status" header="ID"></p-column>
<p-column field="name" header="Title"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Looks like a good question. However, if I may offer some helpful posting tips, we prefer questions to be succinct here. If you can refrain from sad-face emoticons, thanks in advance, please-can-you-helps, stuck-for-X-time pleading and similar chat, it makes any editing a bit quicker. Of course the saving is trivial over one question, but when a person's whole post history is like that, it adds up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working version:
https://embed.plnkr.co/0o42Jb/

You have to add `(onRowClick)="handleRowSelect($event)"` and

```
handleRowSelect(event) {
   console.log('yaaaaaaaaaaaw');
   this.display = true;
   this.personData = event.data.name;
}
```

Comment: it worked! do you know how to make the pop-up show up right where you clicked on? and not in the middle of the page Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! you have to use the **onRowClick** event binding instead of `onRowSelect` event, which is you are using on your external table cal "**MY TABLE**".

So, on your `app.template.html`:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" sortField="room" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="room" expandableRowGroups="true"
        [sortableRowGroup]="false" [expandedRowsGroups]="expandedGroups" (onRowClick)="handleRowSelect($event)">
    <ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData.room}} - INFO</ng-template>
    <p-column field="status" header="ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Title"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And in your `app.component.ts`:

```
handleRowSelect(event) {
    //event.data = Selected row data
    this.display = true;
    this.personData = event.data.name;
}
```

You could get more about on [ngprime docs event section](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).